# How to use a class instance across two JNI methods in Android NDK?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I an new to Android NDK and try to use a C++ class instance across two JNI method calls. I couldn't find a minimalistic example. What steps are necessary to set/get a reference to a C++ class instance across multiple JNI calls from Java?

Some pseudo code:

C++:

```
cOwnClass *oc = NULL; //the reference I want to use across all methods

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_pkgname_clsname_methodset( 
             JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz ){
      oc = new cOwnClass();
      return env->NewStringUTF("set reference");
}


JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_pkgname_clsname_methodcall( 
             JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz ){
      oc->ownMethod(); //oc should be set here
      return env->NewStringUTF("used reference");
}
```

Java:

```
jniinstance.methodset();//creates the class instance
jniinstance.methodcall();//so methodcall should be able to use it
```

Comment: If you don't need to return the `jstring`, you can just return the pointer as long.

Comment: I don't understand, can you provide some code? The jstring is not necessary in my case.